# Instruct Adsense where to place automatic ads

Tags: google-adsense

I have Adsense with auto-optimize enabled.

It places ads all over my pages, sometimes 2 stacked right on top of each other, which is really obnoxious. It also places them in the middle of a piece of content which breaks it up when I don't want it to.

I know I can instruct to it to show more or fewer ads through my Adsense settings.

But is there a way to semantically tell Google where you'd prefer ads to go (or where they should not go) with HTML markup? I have my document mostly split up into `<section>` tags so I would have hoped it would be smart enough to place ads between sections, but it's not doing so.

I was thinking something like `<section data-adsense-inner-ads="no">` to block ads from showing up inside a certain HTML element, for example.